# Prolog - deconstructing goals into individual facts and arithmetic

Tags: prolog

I'm attempting to write a small program that breaks up a given goal into all its smallest parts and eventually evaluates them. So far I have:

```
alien(X) :- fromMars(X), fromSaturn(X); fromJupiter(X), X = 'john'.

fromMars(john).
fromSaturn(john).
fromJupiter(john).

test(true) :- !.
test((Goal1,Goal2)) :- test(Goal1), test(Goal2).
test((Goal1;Goal2)) :- test(Goal1), test(Goal2).
test(X = Y) :- call(X = Y).
test(Goal) :- clause(Goal,Body),test(Body).
```

As far as I can tell so far, this will recursively inspect rules using clause/2 e.g. if I call `test(alien(john)).` . When it reaches the point that `Body` contains only facts such as `fromMars(X), fromSaturn(X); fromJupiter(X), X = 'john'` it will split those using the `test((Goal1,Goal2)) :-` and `test((Goal1;Goal2)) :-` rules, eventually reaching singular facts. When passed a singular fact, clause/2 will instantiate `Body` to true if it can be solved.

Problems arise with arithmetic. In the above program, eventually there will be the singular goal `X = 'john'` This causes an error with clause/2 (private procedure?). I introduced the rule `test(X = Y) :-` to catch this case so I can deal with it another way. However what I really want is a rule that will catch all arithmetic. Obviously I cant write a rule in the style of `test(X = Y) :-` to catch all possible types of arithmetic.

My goal is to eventually write an abductive meta-interpeter that can handle any type of rule thrown at it.

Let me know if none of this makes any sense and I'll try to clarify :)

Comment: In Prolog `=` is the unification operator, arithmetic is handled by the `is` keyword, e.g. `X is Y + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

meta interpreters it's one of the 'strong points' of Prolog. See [this page](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/acomip/acomip.html) from Markus Triska about this interesting theme.

As Little Booby Tables advised, you can capture arithmetic with something simple as

```
test(X is Y) :- X is Y.
```

BTW I think you have a typo here

```
test((Goal1;Goal2)) :- test(Goal1), test(Goal2).
```

should be

```
test((Goal1;Goal2)) :- test(Goal1) ; test(Goal2).
```

*EDIT*: working with operators can be generalized, if required. Just an example of the builtins required:

```
?- X = (1+2), X =.. [F, A, B], current_op(U, V, F).
X = 1+2,
F = (+),
A = 1,
B = 2,
U = 200,
V = fy .
```

Comment: Is there a simple way I could capture goals such as X < Y? Or would I need to write rules for each of the possible operators?

Comment: you can always `call(Goal)`, that could works as a catchall rule. Otherwise, you can play with current_op/3 and =../2, see my edit. It depends on your target...